# why I have not use the hashHistory plugin ,the url has the hash suffixes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**index.js**(previous)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'
import App from './modules/App'

render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>React Router Tutorial</h1>
        </div>
    )
  }
})
```

**url**

```
http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=8cu99t
```

when I remove the `history={hashHistory}`,it also has the hash suffixes after url.
I don`t know why , the code about hashHistory has been remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have hash based routing change hashHistory with browserHistory, your index.js will look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './modules/App'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Please note that if you want to have browserHistory you will need to configure a server, to handle routes on server side, more info can be found [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)